# Using PHP Class in view works, but not in controller

Tags: php, class, controller, snmp

I'm new to PHP and am trying to use the SNMP class in a controller.  I can use it just fine in the view `index.phtml`, but when I move it to the controller I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Project\Controller\SNMP' not found in /Project/module/Project/src/Project/Controller/ProjectController.php on line 113
```

It seems like it's looking for the class within the controller, but I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use any autoloader or `require()` everything?

Comment: Where is the class located? If it's a class in global scope you need to either `use SNMP;` at the top of the controller, or instantiate with `new \SNMP();`

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk in the controller I use `namespace Project\Controller` and then a bunch of `use` statements.  I don't have anything in the view.

Comment: @JimL that did it! I added `use SNMP` to the controller.  That makes sense, but why did it ever work in the view?

Comment: The view probably isn't namespaced, like the controller.

Comment: Thank you!  If you write an answer I'll mark it as resolved, if not I'll write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add `use SNMP` to the top of the controller.  Turns out it worked in the view because the view is not namespaced, while the controller is.